# Issue initiating search on paytm home page through selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, paytm, webdriverwait

Below are the steps I want to automate on paytm via Selenium.

**Steps:-**

1.Launch Paytm.

2.Enter any keyword in Search box displayed at the top of paytm page.Eg."Mobile"

3.Press Enter to navigate to search result page.

Issue:
Keyword written in Search box gets deleted automatically

**My code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class XPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Work\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://paytm.com");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for a Product , Brand or Category']")).sendKeys("mobile");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for a Product , Brand or Category']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Issue is mentioned that the text entered into the search input gets deleted.

Comment: Ah ok. The way the question was originally formatted was unclear and it was easy to miss that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Grasshopper's analysis was in the right direction that *you need to wait for the page to be loaded completely*. I made a small test with your own code to retrieve the *Page Title* soon after invoking the *url*:

- *Code Block* :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://paytm.com");
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  ```
- *Console Output* :

  ```
  Recharge - Online Mobile Recharge & Win 100% Cashback | Paytm.com
  ```
- The initial page with this *Page Title* is an intermitent one when there are *JavaScripts* and *Ajax Calls* still active. So before you send the search *String* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :
- *Ideal Approach* :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://paytm.com");
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Paytm.com – Digital & Utility Payment, Entertainment, Travel, Payment Gateway & more Online !"));
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for a Product , Brand or Category']")).sendKeys("mobile");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for a Product , Brand or Category']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  ```
- *Console Output* :

  ```
  Recharge - Online Mobile Recharge & Win 100% Cashback | Paytm.com
  Paytm.com – Digital & Utility Payment, Entertainment, Travel, Payment Gateway & more Online !
  ```
- *Browser Snapshot* :

[image: paytm]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code block.I must say that the condition you choose to wait is really simple.I have used your code block to automate this task.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to **wait for the page to be loaded completely**. There is a ajax script that is run onload of the page which does some work on the search input textbox. When the page is completely loaded the body tag contains a style attribute. [Wait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for this attribute by using an `ExpectedConditions` of `attributeCOntains` with a `WebDriverWait`.

Try this code -

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(By.tagName("body"), "style", "overflow: visible;"));
WebElement srch = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='search']"));
srch.sendKeys("Hello");
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info behind the root cause of the issue...!It solved my issue.